# ArrayList automatically goes empty

Tags: android, parse-platform

When the app runs, it fetches the users stored on parse server and then adds them to `userList`. But when I try to print the same list with `listView`, the `listView` is empty.

I tried placing logs and found the `userList` has objects when it is in the `findInBackground` method but after it is over, the size of `userList` becomes 0. Please help me retrieve the users' list and display them out.

```
public class Users extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_list);

        Intent TimeTableCalled =  getIntent();
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                if(e==null){
                    for(ParseObject object:objects){
                        Log.i("User", object.get("Name").toString());
                        userList.add(object.get("Name").toString());
                        Log.i("size in loop", String.valueOf(userList.size()));
                    }
                    Log.i("size out of loop", String.valueOf(userList.size()));
                }
                Log.i("size outside if", String.valueOf(userList.size()));
            }
        });

        Log.i("size", String.valueOf(userList.size()));
        ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,userList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String userClicked = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked item is " + userClicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `findInBackground` method executes on a background thread so the code in `onCreate()` that comes after this call actually executes before the code in the callback `done()`, which is only executed after the query completes.

To update the `listView` with the contents from the query just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` at the end of the `done()` method. This requires slightly restructuring `onCreate()` so the adapter can be referenced in `done()`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_list);

    ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,userList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String userClicked = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked item is " + userClicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Intent TimeTableCalled =  getIntent();
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){
                for(ParseObject object:objects){
                    Log.i("User", object.get("Name").toString());
                    userList.add(object.get("Name").toString());
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

`findInBackground` creates a new background thread. The listview and the adapter are on the main thread instead. That's why your `userList` variable is still empty, it's on the main thread while the other thread hasn't finished its job yet. Just modify the code like George said and see what happens.